# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with intermediate value property and increasing over $ \mathbb{R} $ \ $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with intermediate value property and increasing over $ \mathbb{R} $ \ $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f$ is continous on $\mathbb{R}$. How to try?

Comment: Hint: first, show that for $q\in \Bbb Q$,  $\lim_{x\to q, x < q, x\in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: @Didier My problem is how to use that the functions has intermediate value property.

Comment: You should then edit your question and  post what you have done so far (with details) so that we can give you some advices accurately

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be real. Take an irrational number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha >x$. Clealry $f(\alpha)\ge f(x)$, for if not, then $$(f(\alpha),f(x))\subseteq f[(x,\alpha)]\cap \mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$$ by our hypotesis, which is absurd. By the same argument $f(\alpha)\le f(x)$ if $\alpha$ is irrational and $\alpha <x$. Hence $f$ is increasing on the whole line. Can you take it from here?